# WP7 calendar access

Tags: windows-phone-7, calendar

From my research there is currently no access to the WP7 calendar to add a reminder or appointment from an application. Does anyone know if access to the phone's calendar is planned for a future release?

Comment: Seems calender access is coming with Mango. http://windows7themes.net/windows-phone-7-mango-release-date.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Mango release adds the ability to read the calendar but not add to it.

There are currently no published roadmaps or lists of features detailing forthcoming functionality apart from what is in Mango.